# Convert Windows 8 VirtualBox to Bootcamp Partition

Tags: windows-8, mac, virtualbox, virtual-machine, boot-camp

I have installed Windows 8 as a Virtual Machine in Virtual Box a while ago. For performance reasons, I want to create a bootcamp partition from the VDI to avoid re-installation.
Is this possible? And if yes, how?

Comment: FWIW, I tried to do with with a Parallels VDI and was told it was not feasible.  I wound up doing a fresh install into Bootcamp and then adding it back to Parallels and it's worked great ever since.  A lot more work, but fresh Windows installs make me fell better anyway...